# How do I solve this system of ODE's $y' = Ay$ with $A = - \lvert\lvert y\rvert\rvert_2 \cdot \mathbb{I}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $y := y(x) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

$$y' = - \lvert\lvert y\rvert\rvert_2 \cdot y$$
$$\iff y_i' = -\lvert\lvert y\rvert\rvert_2\cdot y_i \space\space\ \forall i\in\{1,..,n\}$$

(This problem appears in an exercise about PDE's in the following form:

Let $V: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n ; V(x,t) := -\lvert x\rvert x$. Solve the following IVP of the ODE:

$$X(y,0) = y \\ \delta_tX(y,t) = V(X(y,t),t)$$

Thanks for any help or approach you can give me.